# How can we update profile picture of user on onCreateUser()?

Tags: chatter, user, connect-api

I use `ConnectApi` to modify picture of `User` in custom salesforce login (Facebook, Twitter...), as follows:

```
global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
    ...
    ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.setPhoto(communityId, userId, fileUpload);
    ...
}
```

How can I update avatar in `Apex` too?

```
global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
   //missing userId because it is the first time of log in
}
```

I need to set fb/twitter avatar to be used for chatter avatar at the same time in register process.

Comment: Off-hand, I don't think there's a means of doing this unless it's through each service's API. To do that, you'd probably need to support OAuth logins. If so, you then *might* be able to use an integration API from a service like Gravitar (used here on SF.SE and many other sites). I'd expect that if you were going to use Twitter or FB, you'd need to do it via their APIs.

Comment: How are you registering your users? Standard SF page? Visualforce action methods? JS Remoting?

Comment: thank you guys. i have found the solution for my issue
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000MJEU